# How to set up a schema for users to authorize access to certain information?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, normalization

I have a social app that has a `user_profile` table with typical standard fields, such as

```
user_id (unique)
name
```

I want to allow users to share among themselves information saved in a separate table called `info`, which has these fields:

```
user_id_fk
agent_name
agent_phone
agent_address
```

So the idea is that if I'm user #1 and you're user #6 - I can authorize you to see the data in my `info` table. Then when you view my profile, a PHP function checks if you're authorized and shows a button linking to a page with my info.

**My question is: what would be the best way to implement this?**

I thought of some solutions but would like your opinion:

[1] create a **new field** in `user_profile` called `info_access`, which would contain a comma separated string containing all users that authorized access. The obvious downside are the limitations of such strings (eg, very difficult to delete a user_id if access to info is revoked, not normalized, etc)

```
3,23,14,12,11
```

[2] create a **new table** called `info_access` which would look like this:

```
user_id_fk    can_access
6             3              
6             23
6             14
6             12
6             11
```

In this case I would query as

`select * from info_access where user_id_fk = 6`

but am unsure how to code the PHP function to check if I will see the button when visiting the profile of someone who authorized me to view the info.

Any suggestions on the schema/code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second approach is the best approach for your problem. Then you can query info_access table to check whether a record for user id of the viewing profile and the user id of the viewer is exists in the info_access table.